# Adding custom code generator

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, intellij-plugin

When I work with certain types of files, such as: Java file, HTML file or Jasmine Test file I can generate some useful code snippets using `Code > Generate` option, for example:

- if I am working with Java file `Code > Generate` allows me to insert getter, setter, constructor etc
- if I am working with HTML file `Code > Generate` allows me to insert an XML tag
- if I am working with Jasmine Text file `Code > Generate` allows me to insert a scaffolding of a test suit or a singe test case

I was wondering if (and how) I can add my own 'generator'. I know I can use Live Templates, but I like the fact that `Code > Generate` gives me a quick list of all available generators.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by writing an IntelliJ plugin and extending this class:

```
com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.Action
```

If you create an intelliJ plugin project (just google `intellij plugin development`for information on how to get started), hit alt-enter somewhere in your project source tree and select `Action`, you will get a dialog which allows you to configure where your action should appear.

You want to place it in relation to another action which already exists, for example right below it. In your case - have a look at the menu group named `GenerateGroup (Generate)`.

Once your action is defined in this manner in your plugin.xml, build and run your plugin in the sandbox.

Now, when your action is triggered, the `AnActionEvent` will be fired which contains references to all the necessary information you need (current project, file, position of cursor within file, psi tree, etc).

Try to get this working so far and come back with any specific questions.

Good luck!